# LEFT JOIN Performance Issue

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance, performance-tuning

I have a view, which has a column that comes from query
[image: QUERY]

Without this query my `count(*)` against that view executes in less than 2 seconds, whereas it takes 2 days for the view with above extra column to show results of `count(*)`.

IMPORTANT POINT : We have 4 environments DEV, TEST, UAT, and PROD. This problem only persists in TEST, whereas DEV and UAT are fine.

Many people are suggesting issue is with `trim(lower())`, but that should cause problem in other environments too, but it does not.

Comment: I hope you don't plan on put this query as a Scaler sub query in a `VIEW`. That `VIEW ` would be slow as molasses.

Comment: it is very slow took 7 days for a distinct of that column to run, please suggest alternatives.

Comment: Post PLAN for that query

Comment: Likely your issue is with the `TRIM(LOWER(...))` function calls in your `ON` clause predicate, which might be causing [cardinality estimate](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/how-do-i-know-if-the-cardinality-estimates-in-a-plan-are-accurate) issues. If you're able to persist the data with those functions already applied, that may solve your problem. Though providing the execution plan for your query (as Michael mentioned) would be the best way to confirm.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Unless you have functional index on this expression `TRIM(LOWER(...))` on both tables Oracle can hardly join these two. So remaining options are to store smaller table into HASH table (HASH JOIN) or to use NESTED LOOP with FULL TABLE SCAN. Most likely your exec. plan flips between these two.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. We hope you enjoy your stay. As a first, could you possibly include the statements as actual code instead of a screen shot? You said that the problem would only persist in TEST and that UAT and DEV would be fine. What's with PROD? How much data in the different environments? Thanks for posting as much details as possible. Hit [edit] to add to your question.

Comment: @JohnK.N. sorry, should have been more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

When I am in this situation (i.e. a query very slow in an instance and fast in another) I check what differences I can find between the environments:

- Compare `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your count query, and for that subquery,  on the different environments, it might give an idea about where to check for differences
- Is the data different accross environments ? A difference in the data *might* explain a difference in performance.
- Are the optimizer statistics up-to-date on all related tables in TEST?
- Do the instances have the same UNDO tablespace size and TEMP tablespace size ?
- Is there a difference in hardware or in CPU/memory load accross environments ?
- Is there a difference in database parameters ?

I hope that helps.